# Json.loads() string that represents a dictionary with unicode values

Tags: python, json

I have a command line tool that takes strings that represent dictionaries and runs traffic

> warp_cli -j '{"warp_ip":"172.18...

Robot Framework is generating parts of these dictionaries and inject unicode keys `u'TCP'`. If there is a unicode key being passed to the dictionary I get:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Example:

```html
import json

streams = [
    {
        "burst_loop_count": "500",
        "protocol": u"TCP",
        "tcp_src_port": "10000",
    },
    {
        "burst_loop_count": "500",
        "protocol": u"TCP",
        "tcp_src_port": "10000"
    }
]

def _create_streams_arg(streams):
    return str(streams).replace("'", '"')

print(json.loads(_create_streams_arg((streams))))
```

Is there a way to: In place map `str(x) or x.encode("ascii", "ignore")` to all values in `Streams` or is there a way to have `json.loads()` properly load something that holds unicode?

I got it working with:

```
def _encode(streams):
    encoded = []
    for stream in streams:
        encoded.append({str(k): str(v) for k, v in stream.iteritems()})
    return encoded
```

But I hoped there might be a cleaner solution

Comment: You should be using `json.dumps()` rather than `str()` to make a proper JSON version of your object.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks, thats true. Will that auto encode?